# Concatenar varchar2 PLSQL

Tags: query, pl-sql

Possuo 2 tabelas com relacionamento `1 to many` e preciso concatenar todos os valores da coluna `Nome` da tabela 2 em apenas uma coluna do select.

Ex.:
[image]

No exemplo, o retorno do que eu preciso seria `Maria, João, José`

Obs.: O banco é PLSQL.

Comment: Tente também com listagg https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jonathan Achei um exemplo bacana desse site** 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/6177bd7a-e2fc-46f4-9646-8fd1480cf14b/concatenar-valores-de-linhas-em-uma-coluna?forum=520

**Tenho a seguinte tabela:**

Codigo  Cliente Produto
1   Jorge   piso
1   Jorge   porta
1   Jorge   torneira

**Preciso que o resultado deste select fique assim:**

Codigo  Cliente Produto
1   Jorge   piso;porta;torneira

**-- Concatenando**

```
SELECT  CODIGO,
        CLIENTE,
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT CAST(PRODUTO AS VARCHAR(10)) + ';' AS [text()]
         FROM TABELA AS O
         WHERE O.CODIGO  = C.CODIGO
         and   O.CLIENTE = C.CLIENTE
         ORDER BY CODIGO
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS Produtos
FROM TABELA AS C
GROUP BY CODIGO,CLIENTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode agrupar e usar um listagg, por exemplo:

```
select t1.ID , listagg(t2.nome, ',') within group( order by t2.nome) as nome
from tabela1 t1
left join tabela2 t2 on t1.id_t2 = t2.id
group by t1.ID
;
```

Só que atendando que o id teria que ser mais ou menos assim

joão, maria e josé teriam que ter o mesmo id